# Facing some issues in recieving the Ajax resonpse

Tags: asp.net-ajax

I am facing some issues in recieving the Ajax resonpse. I am getting the following javascript error in IE

I am updating the gridview based upon the filter selection.

*Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerParserErrorException: Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerParserErrorException: The message received from the server could not be parsed.*

and the following Javascript error in Firefox.

***uncaught exception: [Exception... "'Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerParserErrorException: Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerParserErrorException: The message received from the server could not be parsed.' when calling method: [nsIDOMEventListener::handleEvent]" nsresult: "0x8057001c (NS_ERROR_XPC_JS_THREW_JS_OBJECT)" location: "JS frame :: chrome://firebug/content/spy.js :: callPageHandler :: line 744" data: no]***

But I am not getting the error when I add the attribute EnablePartialRendering="False" in scriptmanager.

I have the same filter and gridview in another page but I am not getting this error. I googled for a solution, I couldnt get
a proper solution. It would be great if someone could help me in finding a solution for this.

Thanks and Regards
Rahul

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have resolved the issue.

In code behind I was calling the `Response.write()` method. After removing this method the code works fine.